# grid/panel scrolls down on opening modal window (Extjs 6 app)

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-classic

I am having panel/grid in extjs 6 application. Whenever i open a modal window  from the panel/grid, the grid/panel scrolls down in the background automatically.

Comment: How are you opening the modal window from panel/grid, please share your code.

Comment: Which version, can you reproduce in a fiddle, does it happen with 6.2.1 also or is this only in the version you use?